# Why does Jacob Black change his hair style?

Tags: character, the-twilight-saga

In the Twilight series Jacob Black has long hair to begin with and then he changed it when he transformed into a wolf. Why did he do that?

Comment: I thought it was because he joined Sam's pack, they all have short haircuts. He also stopped wearing shirts at that point (and maybe got similar tattoos?) like them. Kinda like buzzcuts in the army and similar rituals when joining certain gangs.

Comment: This might to be a question about the *books*, since the answer isn't given in the movies. Or a question asking for *interpretation*, since the answer isn't given in the movies. **Is this Q off-topic for this site?**

Comment: It's because if he had long hair as a wolf he would be a long furred wolf

Answer (score 2):

**Why does jacob black change his hair style?**

Bella asks the same question to Jacob when she sees him with his hair cut off and also asks about his new tattoo. The reason was not mentioned in the movie. When she asks about his hair, instead of asnwering, he quickly changes the topic to Cullens.

In [Twilight Wiki](http://twilight.neoseeker.com/wiki/Jacob_Black), it's mentioned that,

> Twilight and New Moon start off with him having long hair, however,
>   **Jacob decides to cut it off because long hair as a human means long
>   hair as a wolf**, although, he decides to grow it back, because he
>   thinks that Bella likes him more with long hair.

Comment: So any reasonable speculation (based on the movie, the books or his character) *why* he changed his hair?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Made changes to the answer, Thanks for the indication.